Leaflet in angular/typescript application
I'm going to use Leaflet (1.9.4) in Angular (15.1.6)/typescript application.
So in index.html I added
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
 integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
 crossorigin=""/>

In app.component.html
<div id="map"></div>

And app.component.ts looks like
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'LeafletExp';
  latlngs!: L.LatLngExpression[];
  line!: L.Polyline;
  map!: L.Map;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map').setView([50.505, 30.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(this.map);

    this.latlngs = [
      [50.509, 30.086],
      [50.517, 30.081],
      [50.519, 30.083],
      [50.513, 30.06],
      [50.512, 30.047]
    ];

    var myMarker = L.icon({iconUrl: 'assets/myMarker.png', iconSize: [12, 12], iconAnchor: [6,6]});
    for (let index = 0; index < this.latlngs.length; index++) {
      var node = L.marker(this.latlngs[index], {draggable: true, autoPan: true, icon: myMarker}).addTo(this.map);
      //@ts-ignore
      node.id = index;
      node.on('drag', this.dragHandler);
    }

    this.line = L.polyline(this.latlngs, { color: 'blue'});
    this.line.addTo(this.map);
  }

  dragHandler = (e: L.LeafletEvent) => {
    this.latlngs[e.target.id] = e.target._latlng;
    this.map.removeLayer(this.line);
    this.line = L.polyline(this.latlngs, { color: 'blue'});
    this.line.addTo(this.map);
  }
}

For some reasons, for example in order to drag lines along with markers I need to assign IDs to every marker I have on map. So as kindly explained by @ghybs in this discussion when creating every marker I assign it some ID like this
//@ts-ignore    
marker.id = <some id>

It works but as a beginner in typescript/leaflet I'm wondering whether it is normal using //@ts-ignore like this or maybe there is a better way to assign IDs?

I am guessing you want to get rid of @ts-ignore, one way is to use a custom type for marker, where we use the intersection operator (&) to add the index property and that will get rid of your error!
export type ExtendedMarker = L.Marker & {id: number};
...

...
for (let index = 0; index < this.latlngs.length; index++) {
  var node: ExtendedMarker = <ExtendedMarker>L.marker(this.latlngs[index], {draggable: true, autoPan: true, icon: myMarker}).addTo(this.map);
  node.id = index;
  node.on('drag', this.dragHandler);
}
...

FULL CODE:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

export type ExtendedMarker = L.Marker & {id: number};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div id="map"></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  title = 'LeafletExp';
  latlngs!: L.LatLngExpression[];
  line!: L.Polyline;
  map!: L.Map;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map').setView([50.505, 30.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(this.map);

    this.latlngs = [
      [50.509, 30.086],
      [50.517, 30.081],
      [50.519, 30.083],
      [50.513, 30.06],
      [50.512, 30.047]
    ];


    var myMarker = L.icon({iconUrl: 'assets/myMarker.png', iconSize: [12, 12], iconAnchor: [6,6]});
    for (let index = 0; index < this.latlngs.length; index++) {
      var node: ExtendedMarker = <ExtendedMarker>L.marker(this.latlngs[index], {draggable: true, autoPan: true, icon: myMarker}).addTo(this.map);
      node.id = index;
      node.on('drag', this.dragHandler);
    }

    this.line = L.polyline(this.latlngs, { color: 'blue'});
    this.line.addTo(this.map);
  }

  dragHandler = (e: L.LeafletEvent) => {
    this.latlngs[e.target.id] = e.target._latlng;
    this.map.removeLayer(this.line);
    this.line = L.polyline(this.latlngs, { color: 'blue'});
    this.line.addTo(this.map);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
